# map and sort from alphanumeric data

Tags: alphanumeric

I have the file "global power plants" with a column "capacity_in_mw" (with numbers 30, 100, 45, ...) and another column is "primary_fuel" (Coal, Hydro, Oil, Solar, Nuclear, Wind, Coal).

I can generate a map in function of "capacity_in_mw" by setting the condition
plotdata = data.query('capacity_in_mw > 50')

Now, I would like to generate a map in function of "primary_fuel". Because data is alphanumeric, how do I set up the condition?
Furthermore, when making the map, to assign color='black' for Coal, color='green' for Wind, color='yellow' for Solar, ... etc.

Comment: What programming language are you using? Perhaps you can include some codes that you've done.

Answer (score 0):

Python.
I am a novice, but I think I found the solution. It is more of an issue of syntax, to use the == in the query to identify the alphanumeric value.
plotdata = data.query('primary_fuel == "Hydro"')
Also, lesson learned in the future to dig more before posting a question.